# How to do this partial decomposition fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, complex-numbers, factoring, fractions

I factorize the equation $(x+m)^n-x^n$ into $\prod_{q=1}^{n-1}(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))$

Then how do I do the partial fraction to $$\frac{1}{\prod_{q=1}^{n-1}(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is a function which can be written as a product over its roots as $$f(x)=\prod_{f(w)=0}(x-w),$$
where each root $w$ only contributes one term to the product. With the added condition that $f(w)=0\Rightarrow f'(w)\ne 0$, we can show that 
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{f(w)=0}\frac{1}{f'(w)(x-w)}.$$
This answer will be a proof of that fact.

We start by claiming that 
$$\frac1{f(x)}=\prod_{f(w)=0}\frac{1}{x-w}=\sum_{f(w)=0}\frac{b(w)}{x-w}$$
for some coefficients $b(w)$. We multiply both sides by $f(x)$, and see that this becomes
$$1=\sum_{f(w)=0}b(w)\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne w}(x-\phi).$$
Then for any root $z$, we can plug in $x=z$ and get
$$1=\sum_{f(w)=0}b(w)\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne w}(z-\phi)=b(z)\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne z}(z-\phi),$$
because each term in the sum vanishes except for the term $w=z$. Hence 
$$b(z)=\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne z}\frac1{z-\phi}.$$
On the other hand, we have that 
$$\ln f(x)=\sum_{f(w)=0}\ln(x-w),$$
so that 
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{f(w)=0}\frac{1}{x-w}.$$
This is 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{f(w)=0}\frac{f(x)}{x-w}=\sum_{f(w)=0}\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne w}(x-\phi).$$
Again, plug in $x=z$ for any root $z$, and get 
$$f'(z)=\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne z}(z-\phi)=\frac1{b(z)}.$$
Our proof is done.

I will leave it to you to work out the details for applying this formula to your case.

Comment: I don't understand the fifth step. Why does $\sum b(w) \prod (x-\phi)=b(z) \prod (z-\phi)$?

Comment: Is it because of other terms contain $(x-z)$. So,plug in $z$ get $0$.

Comment: when we plug in $x=z$, every $$\prod_{f(\phi)=0,\phi\ne w}(z-\phi)$$ becomes $0$ unless $w=z$, because then $\phi\ne z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{q=1}^{n-1}(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))} = \sum_{q=1}^{n-1}\frac{A_q}{(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))}  $$

This gives
$$1=\sum_{q=1}^{n-1}A_q\frac{\prod_{q=1}^{n-1}(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))}{(x-\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi q}{n}-1))} $$

Cancel the fractions on the RHS, and then, for $1 \leq j \leq n-1$ plugin 
$$x=\frac{m}{2}(i \cot\frac{\pi j}{n}-1)$$
With the exception of $q=j$, all the other terms will become $0$.